# Which letter make which sound in the word "queue"?

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling

As the title says.

```
queue = /kju:/
```

I have currently figured out that

- "qu-" makes the /k/ sound
- "-eu-" makes the /ju:/ sound
- the trailing "e" serves as a sound modifier, similar to ton/tone and cut/cute

But I'm not sure how or why. I hope a linguist can help explain it.

Comment: The word's spelling is taken from French. There is a question about it here: [Etymology of “queue” from “cue”](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/12622)

Comment: I think no letter represents any sound in this word. I suspect the story is really that nobody could figure out the French, so they gave up and just mentioned the first letter. Now the lexical item spelled _queue_ works like a Chinese character -- the sound is almost unrelated to the symbols, and both must be learned as an arbitrary unit.